# uninitialized constant (Name error) with rails-rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

i have created a spec/support/features directory. Added a file named sign_in.rb
with a module

```
module Features
  def sign_in
  end
end
```

but when i added this to spec/rails_helper.rb file as

```
....
  config.include Features, type: :feature
end
```

then while running rake its showing uninitialized constant Features (Name error). I really did not understand this. Asking for help.

Comment: Do you have `Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` line in rails_helper.rb?

Comment: i dont have this line line

Answer (score 3):

all i needed to add following line to rails_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```